# Textfilter webpart doesn't send empty parameter but parameter with previously searched word to external listview

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-part, filter

My Filter in BCS is named 'FirstName'.
Default view has following:

```
<Method Name="GetEmloyees">
  <Filter Name="FirstName" Value="{Param1}" />
</Method>
<ParameterBindings>
  <ParameterBinding  Name="Param1"  Location=""  DefaultValue="" />
</ParameterBindings>`
```

ListView is connected to the textfilter webpart. Everything works well if the textbox in the filter webpart is not empty. If we make it empty, textfilter webpart sends not an empty parameter line, but parameter with previous searched word.

Any ideas?

Update:

I tested with `Location=QueryString(xxx)` in ParametersBinding, set parameters in url and everything works fine, so problem in TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer between SPSlicerTextWebPart and XsltListViewWebPart

Answer (score 0):

I also did something like you and it worked very well. Maybe if you try this tutorial and rebuild your solution?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA101785233.aspx